# conversion of associative array elements to lowercase in php before displaying them

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array having two keys and multiple values,I want to convert associative array elements to lowercase in php.

I am aware abount ucwords,strtolower function but i m not aware about how to use that..

Please guide on this....

Comment: Can you show us your array?  It isn't clear what you mean by "two keys and multiple values".

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
foreach($myarray as &$k => &$v)
{
    $v = strtolower($v);
}
```

notice the & operator which will turn the loop into a reference loop, so you can alter the elements. You can also alter the keys if you like, that's why I put another &. Both & operators are optional but if you want to alter the value, you need the & in $v.

If you don't use & operator on $v, your loop should be:

```
foreach($myarray as $k => $v)
{
    $myarray[$k] = strtolower($v);
}
```

or it could be using `array_map()`

```
$myarray = array_map(function($v) { return strtolower($v); }, $myarray) ;
```

On the other hand, if your array is an array of arrays, you must iterate them as follows:

```
$myarray = array_map(function($v) { return array_map(function($vi){ return strtolower($vi); }, $v); }, $myarray);
```

The for-loop equivalent is trivial.